# Norms, rules or guidelines for calculating and showing ETA/ETC for a process

Tags: c#

*ETC = "Estimated Time of Completion"*

I'm counting the time it takes to run through a loop and showing the user some numbers that tells him/her how much time, approximately, the full process will take. I feel like this is a common thing that everyone does on occasion and I would like to know if you have any guidelines that you follow.

Here's an example I'm using at the moment:

```
int itemsLeft; //This holds the number of items to run through.
double timeLeft;
TimeSpan TsTimeLeft;
list<double> avrage;
double milliseconds; //This holds the time each loop takes to complete, reset every loop.

//The background worker calls this event once for each item. The total number 
//of items are in the hundreds for this particular application and every loop takes
//roughly one second.
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //An item has been completed!

    itemsLeft--;
    avrage.Add(milliseconds);

    //Get an avgrage time per item and multiply it with items left.
    timeLeft = avrage.Sum() / avrage.Count * itemsLeft;
    TsTimeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeLeft);

    this.Text = String.Format("ETC: {0}:{1:D2}:{2:D2} ({3:N2}s/file)", 
        TsTimeLeft.Hours, 
        TsTimeLeft.Minutes, 
        TsTimeLeft.Seconds, 
        avrage.Sum() / avrage.Count);

    //Only using the last 20-30 logs in the calculation to prevent an unnecessarily long List<>.
    if (avrage.Count > 30) 
        avrage.RemoveRange(0, 10);

    milliseconds = 0;
}

//this.profiler.Interval = 10;
private void profiler_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    milliseconds += 0.01;
}
```

As I am a programmer at the very start of my career I'm curious to see what you would do in this situation. My main concern is the fact that I calculate and update the UI for every loop, is this bad practice?

Are there any do's/don't's when it comes to estimations like this? Are there any preferred ways of doing it, e.g. update every second, update every ten logs, calculate and update UI separately? Also when would an ETA/ETC be a good/bad idea.

Comment: I'm sure you've seen timers like this that switch over to "less than a minute" and "less than 30 seconds" when nearing the end of the processing.  If you see the last few estimates jumping around a lot you may wish to consider this.

Comment: That's a great idea, @DanPichelman. Absolutely something to consider.

Comment: If you're interested in the conceptual / design aspects of timers, then this question is on-topic for P.SE.  If you're asking about _that_ specific example of timer code then Codereview would be a better site.

Comment: The code is just an example. I first asked the question on SO and questions with code is usually preferred and since I had the code I added it as a reference. I admit that the text just below the code might be confusing but if you read even further down it should make sense. I'm slightly upset that this was migrated but I guess I just wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks reasonable if one makes the assumption that the average time for item processing is roughly the same for each item.

Updating the UI once a second is ok, updating it more often does not make much sense since the typically user cannot follow that visually either. If this really becomes a bottleneck, you might consider to add some code like

```
if(timeWhenUIWasUpdated < currentTime-1.0)
{
    this.Text = String.Format(/*...*/);
    timeWhenUIWasUpdated = currentTime; // unit: seconds
}
```

(you will have to introduce those two variables `timeWhenUIWasUpdated` and `currentTime` into your code).

Of course, when your progress event gets called more often (for example, several 10,000s a second), you will have to think about further optimizations, since even without the UI you will have to do some time value management or calculations. But as long as this is not the case, keep things simple.

This one here

```
if (avrage.Count > 30) 
     avrage.RemoveRange(0, 10);
```

looks like premature optimization, I guess

```
     avrage.RemoveRange(0, 1);
```

will give you a more smooth behaviour (and I guess you won't notice the difference in running time in most real-world cases).

Furthermore, for testing purposes, you may consider to refactor the average-time calculation into a `SlidingAverageCalculator` class, separating the logic fully from the background worker and the UI display. This will make it really easy to write unit tests for that part of the code.

Comment: Yes, the time for each item is roughly the same in this particular process. I assume an estimated time would be hard to get right if that wasn't the case? Your suggestion on `.RemoveRange` is a good example of what I want to learn, things that would or would not effect the execution time. The last thing I want is for this piece of added functionality to noticeably slow down the process.

Comment: @HjalmarZ: I would not take too many thoughts here on what slows down the process as long as you don't really notice performance losses. At least not when talking about 1 event per second and 30 samples.